# cuda constant memory reference

Tags: cuda, gpu-constant-memory

I have an array in constant memory (it is a global variable) and obtained the reference to it by function call cudaGetSymbolAddress. My kernel runs slowly when I use this reference to fetch the constant data rather than using the global variable. What is the reason for this?

```
__constant__ int g[2] = {1,2};
// __device__ int g[2] = {1,2};

// kernel: use by reference
__global__ void add_1( int *a, int *b, int *c, int *f )
{
    int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    c[tid] = f[0] * a[tid] + f[1] * b[tid];
}

// kernel: use global variable
__global__ void add_2( int *a, int *b, int *c, int *f )
{
    int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    c[tid] = g[0] * a[tid] + f[1] * b[tid];
}

int main()
{
    ......
    // a,b,c are large arrays in device memory of size 40960.

    int *f;
    cudaGetSymbolAddress( (void **)&f, (char *)&g);

    add_1 <<< 160, 256 >>> ( a, b, c, f );

    ......
}
```

This is the sample code and all threads in warp load same location at same time. The commented code is by directly accessing constant memory

**Explanation for why constant memory cache is not used** (by *talonmies*)

The reason is the lack of constant cache.
Cached access only occurs when the compiler emits a specific PTX instruction (ld.const) on a variable explicit marked as being in the constant state space. And the way the compiler knows to do this is when a variable is declared `__constant__` -- it is a static, compile time attribute which effects code generation. The same process can't happen at runtime.

If you pass a pointer in global memory and the compiler can't determine that the pointer in the constant state space, it won't generate the correct PTX to access that memory via the constant cache. Access will be slower as a result.

**Unanswered Question**

Why even when array `g` is declared as `__device__` variable, the code is slower when reference to it used. By seeing the `PTX` code, for loading the global memory to registers:

- 2 instructions of `ld.global.s32` are used, which loads 4 bytes to a register. (in code using reference)
- 1 instruction of `ld.global.v2.s32` is used, which loads 8 bytes to 2 registers, (in code using global variable)

What is the difference and any documentation reference would be appreciated?

Comment: I guess you are not exploiting the constant features. How do you access to the data in global and constant memory?. A snippet of your code will help us to give you a better answer.

Comment: pQB is right. I've just seen talonmies' answer, and with the information given it is impossible to determine which one applies to your problem. Also, what compute capability is your GPU?

Comment: @tera compute capability is 1.3

Comment: I see no `__constant__` declaration at all in the code. How do you call the kernel?

Comment: @tera  I changed the code in question.

Comment: Thanks. With the code as it stands now, I'm convinced my answer is the correct one. :)

Comment: Not so convinced anymore. Could you provide a complete example without omissions as well as the disassembled kernel code from `cuobjdump -sass -fun add` so we might get a better idea of what is going on?

Answer (score 2):

Unlike global memory, accesses to constant memory will get serialized (split into multiple transactions) if they are not uniform (all threads of a (half- for compute capability 1.x) warp access the same address.

So only use constant memory if the accesses are likely to be uniform.

Comment: I do not think it is a non-uniform access, all the threads in the warp request for same address location at for the load instruction.

Comment: True indeed. I had originally thought the accesses indexed by [tid] would be the ones to the constant memory. Could you provide the disassembled kernel code from `cuobjdump -sass -fun add` so we might get a better idea of what is going on?

Comment: And have you tried whether the isolated code as shown above without the rest of your program still shows the issue? The problem might be with something else that we can't see from here...

Comment: Yes .. it is actually a very simple example I am experimenting on.

Comment: Could you then post the complete example?

Comment: I see no update to the code. Looking at PTX is not that helpful because the virtual instructions there do not correspond to machine instructions. `ptxas`, which translates PTX into machine code, runs a second pass of optimizations on it, so the actual machine code may look very different.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18225/discussion-between-t-srinivasa-chaitanya-and-tera)